# Remove material slot via Unity Script

Tags: unity, c#, scripting

I have a lot of duplicated objects, and I need in editor, not in the game, remove specific (18) material slot. Remove not material in slot 18, but remove slot 18. Manually, by hands, it can be done using this button:

[image]

All objects that I need to remove slot from has the next mutuals:

1. Contain "_lod" in the name;
2. Have the same mesh, with the same GUID

I did not find how to get GUID of the given object, so the search, probably need to go by name.

I have never scripted Unity, I even did not write in C# (although I write in C++).

What I done so far: I created an empty game object and assign cs script below to it as a component. `DestroyImmediate(myMaterials[18])`, works almost that I need, but it removes not the slot, but the material on it (and automatically creates default material). I need to remove exactly the slot.

`LookAtPoint.cs`:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEditor;
[ExecuteInEditMode]

public class LookAtPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Iter(GameObject gameObject) // Itterate children
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gameObject.transform.childCount; j++) 
        {
            GameObject a = (GameObject)gameObject.transform.GetChild(j).gameObject;
            MeshFilter viewedModelFilter = (MeshFilter)a.GetComponent("MeshFilter");

            if(viewedModelFilter && viewedModelFilter.mesh && a.name.IndexOf("_lod") != -1) // check if object has mesh and it's name contains "_lod"
            {
                Material[] myMaterials = a.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
                if(myMaterials[18].name.IndexOf("Подоконник")!=-1) // not neccesary check if 18s slot has "Подоконник" name (actually now it is already "Default-Material")
                {
                    DestroyImmediate(myMaterials[18]);
                }
            }
            Iter(a);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        List<GameObject> rootObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        scene.GetRootGameObjects( rootObjects );
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rootObjects.Count; ++i)
        {
            GameObject gameObject = rootObjects[ i ]; // get root objects

            for (int j = 0; j < gameObject.transform.childCount; j++) // enumarate them
            {
                Iter(gameObject); // iteratevely process the children 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you expect to do that more often, then it would be easier to create all those objects as instances of the same prefab. That way you can make a change on the prefab and it automatically gets applied to all the instances. If you want multiple different prefabs which share some properties, then you can use prefab variants They allow you to have prefabs inheritance.

Comment: "So, seems that I have to enumerate all game objects..." sounds like a reasonable plan. How have you tried implementing this plan so far, and what specific step do you need help with?

Comment: @Philipp, yeah, but I need to solve current issue

Comment: @DMGregory, well, I have success, I get material of the object I need by `Material[] myMaterials = object.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;`, but I can't remove it. `Destroy` does not compile, `DestroyImmediate` removes material but not the *slot*. I need exactly remove the slot (object have few materials slots). Probably rewrite my question to specify this

Comment: Did you mean to make a new materials array with only the materials you want and no empty slots, then assign that array to `Renderer.materials`?

Comment: @DMGregory, no, I rewrote my question. Thought about Your comment a bit more, and probably yes

Comment: @DMGregory, I already accidentally removed all slots‍♂️. But Your method seems to be working. Now, probably the task is changed: I need to set materials to empty slots. Oh, no, I did not save, so I can reload the project

Comment: @DMGregory, finally solve it, exactly using Your advice. Would You write an answer, based on the code I provided, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Stdugnd4ikbd When you already have a working solution, then it would be easier if you posted an own answer to your question. Answering your own question is encouraged on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Philipp, I know, but maybe DMGregory want some reputation raise

Comment: Oh please no, no more rep, I beg you! 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as @DMGregory pointed in comments, instead of destroying material, the element of the materials array with needed material should be removed, and new, resized array should be set as component:

```
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEditor;
[ExecuteInEditMode] // for running in editor

public class LookAtPoint : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Iter(GameObject gameObject) // Itterate children
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gameObject.transform.childCount; j++) 
        {
            GameObject a = (GameObject)gameObject.transform.GetChild(j).gameObject;
            MeshFilter viewedModelFilter = (MeshFilter)a.GetComponent("MeshFilter");

            if(viewedModelFilter && viewedModelFilter.mesh && a.name.IndexOf("_lod") != -1) // check if object has mesh and it's name contains "_lod"
            {
                Material[] myMaterials = a.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials;
                if(myMaterials[18].name.IndexOf("Подоконник")!=-1) // not neccesary check if 18s slot has "Подоконник" name (actually now it is already "Default-Material")
                {
                   Material[] aa = new Material[24]; // new array that will be assign. 24 because current length is 25

                   for(int i = 0; i < 24; i++) // fill new array by existing, except 18' element 
                   if(i < 18)
                     aa[i] = myMaterials[i];
                   else if(i >= 18)
                     aa[i] = myMaterials[i + 1];

                   a.GetComponent<Renderer>().materials = aa; // set new array
                }
            }
            Iter(a);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        List<GameObject> rootObjects = new List<GameObject>();
        Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
        scene.GetRootGameObjects( rootObjects );
        
        for (int i = 0; i < rootObjects.Count; ++i)
        {
            GameObject gameObject = rootObjects[ i ]; // get root objects

            for (int j = 0; j < gameObject.transform.childCount; j++) // enumarate them
            {
                Iter(gameObject); // iteratevely process the children 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Summarizing for newcomers like me:

1. In assets, create C# script with code above (notice, that the file name and class name should be the same);
2. Choose any game object on the scene, and open its properties window;
3. In properties window click `Add Component` at the bottom (scroll might be required);
4. Find and choose the ealier created script by file name;
5. By adding the component, the `Start` method will be called, so that's it;

Comment: Rather than using `[ExecuteInEditMode]` and invoking this behaviour in `Start`, you might want to make a function with a `[ContextMenu("Remove Material")]` attribute. Then you can choose when to invoke the method by selecting it from the three-dot menu in the top-right corner of the component inspector.

Comment: @DMGregory, I think, if to talk about the UI, then it would be better to just add some button

Comment: Adding a button is probably best. The advantage of the context menu attribute is that you don't have to write a custom editor script. So it's good for quick & dirty / debug-y stuff like this where you just want it to work without getting in your way or spending more than a bare minimum of engineering time & energy / complexity on it.